# while(condition) { Object.wait() } idiom

Tags: java, multithreading

I know, that we use this idiom for waiting for notification to handle spurious wakeups:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    while(somecond)
        obj.wait();
}
```

If a spurious wake up arises, we'll just check the state and return back to waiting.

But, consider the situation:

1. We begin waiting, and obj.wait() releases lock on obj.
2. Waiting thread is spuriously notified by OS
3. We return to checking condition (with obj lock released due to wait)
4. obj.notify() is called right in that moment.

Yes, condition checking is extremely fast and chances, that we can be in condition checking and not in `obj.wait()`, are negligibly small. In that case we can loose `obj.notify()` call.

Am I misunderstanding something, or we really can loose notification using this pattern?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another thread needs the lock on `obj` to be able to call `obj.notify()`. And it can't have it if your thread is in the while loop not waiting, since your thread also needs the lock on `obj` to be in the while loop.

Comment: But, isn't calling obj.wait() releases lock on obj? Or obj is locked again, since we get spurious wake, leave wait and move to condition checking?

Comment: It releases it, but to be able to execute the operations coming after the wait() call, it needs to reacquire the lock on `obj`. Every instruction inside a synchronized block can only be executed if the thread holds the lock.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `obj.wait()` will not return until an `obj.notify()` has been called. However, you might fail to respond to an `obj.notify()` if *another* thread is also waiting and the system decides to notify that thread instead. If you want to avoid that, you can use `obj.notifyAll()`. If only one thread is waiting, you cannot lose the notification with this pattern.

Note that the other thread cannot call `obj.notify()` unless it holds the lock. If this thread is busy checking the condition, then it has the lock and the other thread cannot issue a notification. The `synchronized` block is essential to the operation.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you present, Thread A is evaluating the condition, and Thread B is calling `notify` such that Thread A misses the `notify` call

**This scenario would not be possible** for that `notify` to be called since it must own the lock that Thread A is using in the synchronized block - only one thread can own that lock at once.  See the [javadoc on `notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The modifications to the state we are checking should be made, while the lock on `obj` is held by whomever calls `obj.notify()` afterwards. So, assuming we are currently checking the state, we are also holding the lock on `obj`.

If we are getting a spurious wake up, and the state has not changed, no one should have called `obj.notify()`. If the state has changed and we we miss a `obj.notify()`, it does not matter: For all intends, a spurious wake up and a wakeup by a call to `obj.notifiy()` have the same effect now.

The lesson is, that the state we are checking for should only be changed, while whoever is changing the state holds a lock on the object we are waiting on.

Answer (score 1):

Since most of the answers insist on the impossibility of the scenario it’s worth to adjust that:

It is always possible to have a call to `notify` without a matching `wait`ing thread. This might happen when the notifying thread invokes `notify` *before* the other thread even entered the entire `synchronized` block. The `notify` method might even have been called multiple times before any thread enters a `synchronized` block to `wait` and the `wait`-`notify` mechanism won’t count these.

So you have to handle the case that you missed a `notify`, e.g. by checking the condition within the `synchronized` block before calling `wait`. But by doing so you add the possibility to process and reset the condition while the matching `notify` is indeed pending.

Therefore you must be always aware of the possibilities that either

- you may have missed one or more `notify` invocations
- you may receive an obsolete `notify`

That’s why the correct handling loop likes like that

```
synchronized(obj) {
    while(somecond)
        obj.wait();
}
```

From an application’s point of view there is no difference between outdated pending `notify`s and the spurious wakeups generated by the JVM/OS without associated `notify` invocations. That’s why there is no attempt to prevent spurious wakeups by the JVM. The effort would be wasted as the logic wouldn’t change.